# Recommended Authorisation framework for Scala Play 2.4

Tags: scala, spring-mvc, playframework, authorization

Are there any recommended Authorisation framework for Play framework 2.4?

As I from a Java background, not sure there are some similar solution as Spring MVC annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project with the most stars working without any change with Play! **2.4** on Github is [Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette). (I think that it is a fork of SecureSocial.)

Unlike SecureSocial which only supports Play! 2.3, it works as it is with Play! 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own solutions **but** you should probably don't do this unless you want to deal with all problems yourself, if you are planning to use it in production use [SecureSocial](http://securesocial.ws/), it provides both OAuth1/2 and simple username/password and even custom authentication schemes. And providing a simple way to do this; have both java/scala apis with annotations for java and an idiomatic class replacement way for scala. For example in scala:

```
object Application extends Controller with securesocial.core.SecureSocial {  
  def index = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
   Ok(views.html.index(request.user))
  }
}
```